# weighted random order

Tags: random

I have a field in a channel called "weight" where the user can set a number between 0-1000. On page load I want to generate a random number between 0 and "weight" for each entry, and then sort the entries based on these numbers.

How can I do this with Craft 2/Twig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be a lot cleaner/more efficient to do this from a custom plugin in PHP, but if you want to do it from a template, this should work:

```
{% set entryArr = {} %}

{# Grab all of the entries in the section #}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('news').find() %}

{# Loop through them generating a random number between 0 and the weight custom field #}
{% for entry in entries %}
    {% set entryArr = entryArr|merge({(entry.slug): random(range(0, entry.weight))}) %}
{% endfor %}

{# Sort the array by the ascending value maintaining the keys #}
{% set entryArr = entryArr|sort %}

{# print them off #}
<ul>
{% for slug, randomNumber in entryArr %}
    {% set entry = craft.entries.slug(slug).first() %}
    <li>{{ entry.title }} - Max Range: {{ entry.randomNumber }} - Random Number: {{ randomNumber }}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```